# Check for empty TextBox controls in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

Ive got a Form application in VB.NET.

I have many text boxes on one form (about 20). Is there anyway to check them all at once to see if they are empty instead of writing out a massive line of code to check each one individually such as

```
If txt1.text = "" Or txt2.text="" Then
    msgbox("Please fill in all boxes")
```

That just seems like a long way around it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could also use LINQ:

```
Dim empty =
    Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Length = 0)
If empty.Any Then
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}",
                    String.Join(",", empty.Select(Function(txt) txt.Name))))
End If
```

The interesting method is [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx#Y0)

The same in query syntax(more readable in VB.NET):

```
Dim emptyTextBoxes =
    From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    Where txt.Text.Length = 0
    Select txt.Name
If emptyTextBoxes.Any Then
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}",
                    String.Join(",", emptyTextBoxes)))
End If
```

Comment: hi mate, this worked but it doesnt work for tab pages. try adding in "tabcontrol1" which it allows but it doesnt allow a specific page such as "tabcontrol1.tabpage2" any ideas?

Comment: @Dr.Pepper: It works the same: `Dim empty = Me.TabControl1.TabPages(1).Controls.OfType...`

Comment: AHH, thats the string i was looking for! i missed off the "me." lol cheers bud

Comment: @Dr.Pepper: No, it would work without the `Me` but not with `tabpage2` but rather with `TabPages(2)` because [TabControl.TabPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages.aspx) is a collection.

Comment: yeah just realised that - missed the brackets. Cheers :)

Comment: @Dr.Pepper How would we bet the VB.Net code to highlight the empty text boxes background yellow?

Comment: @MaxineHammett this question is over 7 years old. Start a new thread.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the Validating event of the TextBox controls, with an error provider control (just add one to your form):

```
Private Sub TextBox_Validating( sender As System.Object,  e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating, TextBox2.Validating, ComboBox1.Validating
        Dim ctl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
        If ctl.Text = ""
            e.Cancel = True
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(ctl,"Please enter a value")
        End If
End Sub
```

Then you can just call:

```
ErrorProvider1.Clear()
If Me.ValidateChildren()
        ' continue on
End If
```

The nice thing about this is that the user is informed about which textbox is missing and required. This works with other controls besides textboxes, so you can provide a more complete solution.  Also, if you get to a later point where one or two textboxes don't need to have values, you simply do not validate them instead of having to add special cases in your loops.

Finally, if you don't want to type out all of the controls, then you could do this in form load:

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf(c) is TextBox or TypeOf(c) is ComboBox
        AddHandler c.Validating, AddressOf Me.TextBox_Validating
    End If
Next
```

Comment: i like the idea, it just doesnt get around the whole having to enter all 20+ textboxes into the Sub. Im looking for the lazy mans way :P

Comment: You can do it all in the IDE, by just assigning the event to the textbox's validating event.  In the long run, it will probably save you time, as you can put all of your validation logic in one place.

Comment: @JohnKoerner - this is crazy good! In regards to ErrorProvider1 is there a way for me to display the RedExclamationmark next to each control at once. Right now it's only doing it for the first control is recognizes as empty? Thanks in advance

Comment: I like that bit about adding the handlers automatically but I'm getting "Option Strict On disallows late binding"

Answer (score 5):

A *very simplistic* approach would be to gather all the `TextBox` controls in a sequence using the [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) LINQ method and then iterate through it in a [For Each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) loop:

```
Dim textBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox);

For Each t In textBoxes
   If String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text) Then
       MsgBox("...")
       Exit For
   End If
Next t
```

Comment: how do you mean in a sequence? such as txt1, txt2, txt3?

Comment: I mean a sequence of items like an array or a [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). What version of the .NET Framework are you using? Is it a WinForms app?

Comment: using visual studio 2010, general form application for college project

Answer (score 1):

I found this, perhaps you can modify it to check if all textboxes are clear rather than what it currently does which is just clear all textboxes

```
Public Sub ClearTextBox(ByVal root As Control)
For Each ctrl As Control In root.Controls
ClearTextBox(ctrl)
If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
End If
Next ctrl
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
ClearTextBox(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm, interesting, will give it ago and report back. Nice thinking outside the box ;) haha

Answer (score 1):

If `TextBox` field is empty then the message box will appear saying "Complete Entry!".

```
Dim t
For Each t In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then
        If t.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Complete Entry!")
            Exit Sub
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Sub for check Empty Textbox  in GroupBox, you can use this:

```
Public Sub CheckEmptyTextbox(Byval groupbox as GroupBox)

Dim txt as control

For Each txt in groupbox.Controls

  IF TypeOF txt is Textbox then

     IF txt.Text="" Then


      MsgBox("Please Input data to textbox.")

      Exit For

     End IF

  End IF

Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Public Class freestyle

```
Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    If Trim(TextBox3.Text) = "" And Me.Visible Then
        MsgBox("fill in the textbox")
        TextBox3.BackColor = Color.Yellow


    Else
        ' MsgBox("great one !!!")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    If Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" And Me.Visible Then
        MsgBox("fill in the textbox")
        TextBox2.BackColor = Color.Yellow


    Else
        'MsgBox("great one !!!")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    If Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" Or Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Or Trim(TextBox3.Text) = "" And Me.Visible Then
        MsgBox("Please fill the necesary", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        TextBox1.Focus()

    Else
        MsgBox("Nice Work !!!")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    If Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" And Me.Visible Then
        MsgBox("fill in the textbox")
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow


    Else
        ' MsgBox("great one !!!")

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class