# Send Null to oracle if the textbox value is empty

Tags: vb.net, oracle, textbox, null

I need to send NULL to oracle from the text box's if there is no value being entered.

I have like 30 text box's. I can't use the cmd.Parameters.Add statement for each and every text box.

Please advice with some code.I am using the web services to communicate with DB.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check all the textbox at once if empty or not without doing event to all textbox.
[This is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489671/check-for-empty-textbox-controls-in-vb-net)

```
Dim emptyTextBoxes =
    From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    Where txt.Text.Length = 0
    Select txt.Name
If emptyTextBoxes.Any Then
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}",
                    String.Join(",", emptyTextBoxes)))
End If
```