# How to apply one error provider to all empty textboxes VB.net 2010

Tags: validation, error-handling, textbox, string

I have this block of code, using too many error providers assigned to each textbox. Is there any other way (or shorter way) particularly to set one error provider to all textboxes?

```
If txtHolidayName.Text = "" Then
    ErrorProvider2.Clear()
    ErrorProvider3.Clear()
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtHolidayName, "Holiday name is required!")
    txtHolidayName.Focus()
ElseIf dtpHoliday.Value < Date.Today And txtHolidayName.Text <> "" Then
    ErrorProvider1.Clear()
    ErrorProvider3.Clear()
    ErrorProvider2.SetError(dtpHoliday, "Holiday date must be greater than the current date!")
    dtpHoliday.Focus()
ElseIf txtHolidaySalary.Text = "" And dtpHoliday.Value > Date.Today Then
    ErrorProvider1.Clear()
    ErrorProvider2.Clear()
    ErrorProvider3.SetError(txtHolidaySalary, "Holiday salary is required!")
    txtHolidaySalary.Focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out....

```
Private Sub TextBox_Validating( sender As System.Object,  e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating, TextBox2.Validating, ComboBox1.Validating
    Dim ctl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
    If ctl.Text = ""
        e.Cancel = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(ctl,"Please enter a value")
    End If
End Sub
```

In the private sub part - change textbox2.validating to your control names. Then use this to call this function....

```
ErrorProvider1.Clear()
If Me.ValidateChildren()
    ' continue on
End If
```

I didn't do this. John Koerner did it. Here's the link
[Check for empty TextBox controls in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489671/check-for-empty-textbox-controls-in-vb-net)