# Check for empty text boxes when using lists

Tags: vb.net, list, textbox

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub EditarToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EditarToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim ctlEditable = {txtCodigo, txtDeudor, txtOportunidad, drpBanca, txtEjecutivo, drpGarantia, txtCIIU, dteFecha, txtAnalista, drpEstatus, drpConcepto, dteUltAct, txtIngresos, drpCumplimiento, txtROA2, txtIE2, txtAnt, txtAct, txtCovenants, drpFaltas, txtOportunidades, txtCostos, txtPMAA}.ToList()
        Dim ctlText = {txtCodigo, txtDeudor, txtOportunidad, drpBanca, txtEjecutivo, drpGarantia, txtCIIU, dteFecha, txtAnalista, drpEstatus, drpConcepto, dteUltAct, txtIngresos, drpCumplimiento, txtROA2, txtIE2, txtAnt, txtAct, txtCovenants, drpFaltas, txtOportunidades, txtCostos, txtPMAA}.ToList()
        Dim ctlPerma = {txtRAS, txtActividad, txtTipo, txtMultaPot, txtPotencial}.ToList()
        Dim control As Control
        For Each control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf (control) Is TextBox Then
                Dim txtBox As TextBox = control
                If txtBox.Text.Length = 0 Then
                    ctlEditable.ForEach(Sub(c) c.Enabled = False)
                Else
                    ctlEditable.ForEach(Sub(c) c.Enabled = True)
                    Return
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

I'm trying to check if the text boxes are empty before enabling them for edit; so basically if they're empty you can't edit, but if there's text you can. I tried the answer in: [Check for empty TextBox controls in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489671/check-for-empty-textbox-controls-in-vb-net) but didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your TextBoxes inside of panels?  Your logic doesn't quite make sense though, since the *last* textbox your loop finds will determine the enabled property in the ctlEditable list.

Comment: @LarsTech the text boxes are on a plain form...thanks for the tip, I'll look into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is work out whether or not to enable them and only then execute the foreach loop to enable / disable.

```
    Dim enable = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Any(Function(t) t.Text.Length > 0)
    ctlEditable.ForEach(Sub(c) c.Enabled = enable)
```

However I suspect you'll want to use `ctlEditable` instead of `Me.Controls` as `Me.Controls` only contains the top level controls of a form.

Comment: Thanks @floatingkiwi ! worked like a charm! (I used `ctlEditable` instead of `Me.Controls`)