# How to check if a textbox is empty VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to test if a textbox is empty for validation purposes, rather than using if x = "". Instead I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. Currently I have:

```
If txtDob Is Nothing Or txtFirst Is Nothing Or txtGender Is Nothing Or txtLast Is Nothing Or txtPostcode Is Nothing Or txtStreetName Is Nothing Or txtStreetNo.Text Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("One or more fields have not been completed")
        Return
    End If
```

However, this doesnt seem to work, can someone show me the correct method or another way to do this please?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't notice that thread. I'll take attention to it next time.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDob.Text) Then           
  ' "Contains Empty value or Null Value" 
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
Dim emptyTextBoxes =
    From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    Where txt.Text.Length = 0
    Select txt.Name
If emptyTextBoxes.Any Then
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}",
                    String.Join(",", emptyTextBoxes)))
End If
```

Code from Tim Schmelter's answer on [Check for empty TextBox controls in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9489884/1070452)

Comment: Sorry but could you explain that code, so I understand it for future reference?

Comment: Please ***credit the author of the code***! This is very unprofessional. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489671/check-for-empty-textbox-controls-in-vb-net

Comment: First declare `emptyTextBoxes` as the selection of any text property with length 0. then check if there is any textbox with length = 0 and show it.

Comment: I can't comment without 50- reputation. @Zaggler

Comment: Its the same exact answer; nothing is added to tailor it to the user's needs and you did not even upvote Tim's answer which you obviously found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `Text` property.

```
If txtDob.Text = string.Empty Then
```

With your Code you're checking if the Object of your TextBox is nothing, not the content. As long as the TextBox exists, your condition would return false.

Comment: So would the above code work if I instead did txtdob.text is nothing?

Comment: No. `is nothing` just work, if there is no instance of the Object. The Textbox Text is empty but not nothing. `txtDob Is nothing` would be true if you dispose your Textbox with `txtDob.Dispose()`. On this way the instance of the Control gets "released" and don't exists. Is nothing don't compare string content.

Comment: @Irgthrill I would recomend you this article about `nothing` to understand the meaning of it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx

Comment: Oh I see, theres a difference between the empty and nothing. Thanks!